# how do I resolve java.lang.IllegalAccessError in a maven multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot-actuator

When I run mvn test on one of the modules of a multi-module, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory (in unnamed module @0x76329302) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x76329302
```

The full console listing is:

```
% cd ../home-encryption; mvn deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
[INFO] Not installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]  * Preexisting staging related goal bindings found in 1 modules.
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< ws.daley.home:home-encryption >--------------------
[INFO] Building home-encryption 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ home-encryption ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ home-encryption ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ home-encryption ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-encryption/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ home-encryption ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ home-encryption ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory (in unnamed module @0x76329302) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x76329302
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.557 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-15T20:54:00-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project home-encryption: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/tim.daley/AixNPanes/HomeServer/home-encryption/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory (in unnamed module @0x76329302) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x76329302
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory (in unnamed module @0x76329302) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x76329302
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

my home-parent/pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-M1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ws.daley.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>home-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>home-parent</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1-jre</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</nexusUrl>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>15</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>pihome</id>
            <name>PiHome</name>
            <url>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>pihome</id>
            <url>http://lemon:8081/repository/pihome/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
<!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId> 
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId> <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> 
    <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId> 
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId> <version>5.7.1</version> 
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId> <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId> 
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> 
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-console</artifactId> 
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> 
    <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-jfr</artifactId> 
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> 
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-reporting</artifactId> 
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> 
    <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId> 
    <version>1.7.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit-platform-testkit</artifactId> <version>1.7.1</version> 
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId> <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId> 
    <version>5.7.1</version> </dependency> -->
```

The module is home-encryption and it has home-encryption/pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ws.daley.home</groupId>
        <artifactId>home-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../home-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>home-encryption</artifactId>
    <name>home-encryption</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The only source file in the project is:

```
package ws.daley.home.encryption;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {
    private static Map<String, SecretKeySpec> secretKeys = new TreeMap<>();

    public static SecretKeySpec secretKey(String myKey) {
        SecretKeySpec secret = secretKeys.get(myKey);
        if (secret == null)
            try {
                byte[] key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
                MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                key = sha.digest(key);
                key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
                secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
                secretKeys.put(myKey, secret);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        return secret;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = secretKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = secretKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the only test is:

```
package ws.daley.home.encryption;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@SpringBootTest(classes=AES.class)
class AESTest {
    @Test
    void secretKeyTest() {
        SecretKeySpec spec = AES.secretKey("Test Key!");
        assertEquals("", spec.getAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

My maven version shows:

```
% mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 15.0.2, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc., runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-15.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I have several other modules that have similar pom.xml files as this module. They run just fine.

I'v tried a number of things suggested online with no success. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need to use JPMS. We have a fix in the future version, see [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1809).
Pls use the workaround `<useModulePath>false</useModulePath>` which disables JPMS.

Comment: Changing the surefire plugin definition as follows did the trick!     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
     <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>